# Style sibling selector with a:visited

Tags: html, css, visited

I am showing an image element when the user hovers over a link-- this is working.

I would now like to make that image always visible to the user when they return to the site... My attempt below was (I think) foiled because of restrictions on the :visited selector.

Is there a way to get around these restrictions to make this method work?  Is there another selector I can use to the same effect?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 60%;
}

a:visited {
  color: red;
}

a:visited + #image {
  visibility: visible;
}

a:hover{
  color: white;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}

a:hover + #image{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: you wuold need aserver side script or you could use storage on their computer with javascript. Do they login to your site, or have a username or something ?

Answer (score 3):

This way we can do.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 60%;
}

a:visited {
  color: red;
}

a:visited + #image {
  visibility: visible;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}

a:hover + #image {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#hello">Hello</a> - Click this to make it visited.
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/" alt="Image" id="image" />
```

Also you can do this way, by using `:target` attribute.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 30%;
  left: 60%;
}

a:visited {
  color: red;
}

#image:target {
  visibility: visible;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}

a:hover + #image {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#hello">Hello</a> - Click this to make it visited.
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/" alt="Image" id="image" />
```

Check this out from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>:target pseudoclass example</title>
    <style>
      #hidden-element {
        display: none;
      }

      #hidden-element:target {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#hidden-element">Show the Hidden Element</a></p>
    <div id="hidden-element">
      <p>You have unhided me!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me, in Chrome, neither of the 2 first samples shows the image after one visited the link...and it shouldn't either, as one could actually trace a users if it worked.

Comment: @LGSon I hope you are aware about the fact that this is a huge privacy breach and all the browsers fixed it by mid 2015. 

Comment: Yes, I am, and the reason I posted the comment, as as of today, this answer is actually incorrect ;) ... and I found this looking for a dupe for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149634/style-siblings-of-visited

Comment: @LGSon Made it a community wiki now as it's obsolete. Feel free to add more details about the incorrectness.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to what the `:visited` selector can style: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

It might seem that you've run up against one.