# Style siblings of visited

Tags: html, css, visited

I have HTML looking something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>...
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply a style to all sibling links of the visited link.
I tried:

```
ul>li>a:visited ~ a{
    color: green !important;
}
```

And nothing happens. But

```
ul>li>a:first-child ~ a{
    color: green !important;
}
```

works perfectly fine.
Applying a style to `<li>` with a visited link works for me, too.

Comment: you cannot, styling using `:visited` is restricted to some styles (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#Styling_restrictions)

Comment: Does that mean you want to target links both before and after the visisted one? ... If yes, then no, you cannot do that for siblings being positioned before the visited one in the markup. For that you need a script.

Comment: With `:visited`, along with limitations of which properties you can style, you can't target other elements other than the link itself, hence your first style doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to hack the above a bit, this selector should work. Here, am trying to select the sibling of any `a` nested under `li`, and later, I ignore the `a` which are not visited yet. This should simulate the effect you are looking for.

---

**Preview for the same**:
[image: Select visited siblings]

---

```css
ul > li > a ~ a:not(:visited) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://medium.com">Medium</a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://medium.com">Medium</a>
    <a href="https://medium.com">Medium</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your solution selects all not visited links on page (I already tried this one). I wanted all unvisited links in list only if there is visited link in the same list.

Comment: @СергейЯхницкий sorry but your requirement is confusing to me

Comment: If you have several list items, then your code selects all unvisited links in all list items and even in the other lists. I tried to select unvisited links inside the list item only if it already has a visited link.